# Without using toUpper(), toLower(), length(), at() or [] -- Convert "Hey!! THERE!" to "hEy!! tHeRe!"

Tags: c++, ascii

```
void crazyCaps(string& str){
size_t i = 0;
size_t strLength = str.length();  // this line violates the rule as mentioned in the title

while (i < strLength) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
        if (str[i] >= 'A' && str[i] <= 'Z')   // this line violates the rule as mentioned in the title
            str[i] += 32;
    }
    else {
        if (str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z') 
            str[i] -= 32;
    }
    i++;
}
```

> My input: "Hey!! THERE!"
>
> My output: "hEy!! tHeRe!"

I'm able to convert the characters to uppercase and lowercase without using toUpper() and toLower() function. However, I'm still using length() and []. So my question is how do you convert "Hey!! THERE!" to "hEy!! tHeRe!" without using length() or [] and toUpper() or toLower().

Comment: If my question is not clear, let me know and I will edit it again.

Comment: Was this an interview question, or a homework assignment?

Comment: Is this a school exercise?  If it is, it is teaching you the wrong way to do things.  Converting a character to upper or lower case is done correctly by the `tolower` and `toupper` functions. Not every language is English.  Second, use `std::transform` and a lookup table.

Comment: Hint: iterators. Did your instructor cover the topic of iterators, in class?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I have to do this by hand. I can't use any functions

Comment: @SamVarshavchik do you have an example of the code? I may understand if I see what the code looks like.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik can you show me the iterator? I remember my professor talked about that in class, but I couldn't remember what iterator looks like

Comment: @BarryP -- Just a little bit for your further education, [here is the reason to use `std::tolower`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/tolower).  Same thing for `std::toupper`.  Your teacher never stated that the language is purely English or the locale is "C".  If you have accented characters, how is your code going to translate them without using those functions?  The state that current C++ education is in...wow.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I don't understand half of what you are saying, but thanks for the input XD

Comment: @BarryP -- What is the upper case / lower case for the Greek letters? It isn't only English that has upper / lower case.  So what I'm saying is that the restriction to **not** use `tolower` and `toupper` is silly and counterproductive to your learning  -- those functions handle the characters that you may not know what their upper / lower case versions are.

Answer (score -1):

`str[i]` is equivalent to `*(str + i)`. Internally, compiler converts `str[i]` to `*(str + i)`.

This implies, `str[i]` = `*(str + i)` = `i[str]`

Also, a string always ends with `\0` (null character). Using these two facts, you can construct something like this:

```
int i = 0
while(*(str + i) != '\0') {
    //change the case by adding or subtracting 32
    i++;
}
```

EDIT: By string, I mean regular C string and not `std::string`

Comment: A `std::string` can have embedded NULLs.  Your solution will not work for something like `std::string s = "\0abc";`

Comment: I never see *(str+i) nor '\0' from the lecture

Comment: *str[i] is equivalent to *(str + i)* is only true if `str` is a pointer type.  Since it is a `std::string` it won't do what you expect.